# Не применились миграции в phpmyAdmin

Tags: yii2, phpmyadmin

Приветствую, помогите...Я создала миграции, в файле они применились а в базе данных нет, в чём может быть причина?

Вот они в файле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в базе данных их нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для создания миграций запускала:

```
yii.bat migrate
yii.bat migrate/create add_user_email_confirm_token
yii.bat migrate/create rename_user_table
yii.bat migrate/create create_user_networks_table
yii.bat migrate/create change_users_field_requirements
```

при этом никаких ошибок не обнаруживалось

Comment: Напишите, как Вы пытались применить миграции. Какие команды Вы запускали в консоли и какие ошибки получили. Так же проверьте подключение к базе данных

Comment: `php yii migrate` запускали?

Comment: Да конечно запускала

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! Нужно было мне в консоле после каждого добавления миграций их подтверждать командой

```
$ yii.bat migrate
```